# How to delete or clear the svn:ignore list from base repository recursively. I want to clear all svn:ignore

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

How to delete or clear the svn:ignore list from base repository recursively. Basically I want no filter or files in the ignore list without having to track down every single file and create them to unignore them individually.

A previous developper added a bunch of files to the ignore list at random levels of the repository and I want to remove ALL elements of the ignore list.

Don't want to do it manually for each single file/folder.

Answer (score 0):

Get all definitions: `$ svn propget -R svn:ignore .` and delete with [`svn propdel`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propdel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Setting an empty `svn:ignore` property in the top-level folder and checking the *Apply property recursively* option seems to do the trick:

[image: Add Properties]

It only changes the folders that already had the property set and it seems to actually remove the property altogether.

Comment: is the image broken, not only for me?

Comment: @Line It's hosted at `https://i.imgur.com/1fvGlRr.png`. Tracking blocker or firewall maybe?

Comment: you're right. anyway, I figured out one needs to right click on directory -> Tortoise SVN -> Properties -> click on property -> click (not arrow) Edit..., there is "Apply property recursively" checkbox, then ok