# svn - move "ignore" pattern up

Tags: svn, version-control

I have multi-directory nested structure of project.
Over the time, to lot of those directories ignore pattern (*.iml) was added.

Now I would like to remove all those directory-specific *ignore* properties, and add one on the top level.

Is it somehow possible without stepping manually into each directory?

If not, it would be helpful to even get a list of those easily, although if it will appear there are a lot of them, I'm not sure it will be wort it.

Comment: With TortoiseSVN you can [remove the property altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57021143/13508). Not sure if that helps here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you, but I'm afraid I can't use it here - I don't want to affect other *ignores*, only this one.

Comment: In fact, I don't think I actually tested it in this scenario. I have no idea if it merges existing values or not.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I just tested it and (as expected) it replaces whole *ignore* property, so those that existed before, are replaced - can't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`svn pg -R svn:ignore .` on top-level dir (maybe add `-v`) in order to get full list of all ignores in tree

You can save each property to separate file, edit it (remove unwanted definition) and replace ignore-list with a bundle of `svn ps svn:ignore -F ...`